# how to read properly a soap service in php that has special characters

Tags: php, laravel, soap, soap-client

I am using the php library SoapClient in a Laravel project to get information of a web service, the service sometimes service returns this kind of responses in its xml:

```
 &#xfffd;
```

when I test the web service using the linux console, I get this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:SearchResponse xmlns:ns2="http://xxxxx"><return><CodigoError>009</CodigoError><Error>c&#xfffd;digo....</Error></return></ns2:SearchResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

and this the request I use in console:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?wsdl' \
  --header 'Content-Type: text/xml' \
  --data '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tns="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    >
    <soap:Body>
        <tns:Search>
            <code>123</code>
           .....  
        </tns:Search>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'
```

In php I use this:

```
$options = [
            'trace' => true,
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            'connection_timeout' => 30
        ];

$client = new SoapClient('https://xxxxxxxxxxx?WSDL', $options);

$params = [
            'code'=>'123'
        ];

$result = $client->Search($params);

return response()->json($result);
```

it is returning this:

```
{
    "return": []
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: First check what `$result` actually contains, rather than relying on the faulty output. Continue working backwards from there.